# should I use drf APIView's alongside with django Views in a production project?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am just learning djangorestframework and my question is: "should I use APIView's alongside with Views?" my friend told me that I should have an api app and for some parts you should only use normal django Views and other parts related to admins the APView.
Now I'm a bit confused what should my project structure look like for exmple in an ecommerce project?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you only need to create apps for different applications, aka different projects. For example if your main project is `google.com`, then you can create new app in django for `maps.google.com` or for `mail.google.com`, but if it is the same project you need to create a different `views_api.py`, and move this api there

Comment: It's up to you, if you need an API then you have to use DRF, if not then use pure Django, but in most cases or in real-world projects we are building a RESTFul API or GraphQL, so my advice as a back-end is to focus on how to design a good RESTFul API, Database, clean code, and so on...